# Implement download progress bar

Tags: codenameone

While downloading a file, it shows download progress in the notification or somewhere. 
But i think it is not by default in cn1 app. I want to add progress listener. How to make it work??

```
if (!FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(filename)) {               
        com.codename1.io.Util.downloadUrlToFile(PdfUrl, filename, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case used the code below.

```
/**
 * Adaptation of Util.downloadUrlTo
 */
private boolean downloadUrlToAdapt(String url, final String fileName, boolean storage, final Slider slider) {
    final ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest();
    cr.setPost(false);
    cr.setFailSilently(true);
    cr.setUrl(url);
    if (storage) {
        cr.setDestinationStorage(fileName);
    } else {
        cr.setDestinationFile(fileName);
    }

    NetworkManager.getInstance().addProgressListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (evt instanceof NetworkEvent) {
                NetworkEvent e = (NetworkEvent) evt;
                if (e.getProgressPercentage() >= 0) {
                    slider.setText(e.getProgressPercentage() + "%");
                    slider.setProgress(e.getProgressPercentage());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);

    return cr.getResponseCode() == 200;
}
```

I needed to show video download progress. I hope it helps.

Comment: thankyou @Sadart Abukari ...  hav you implemented cancel download too? It was of great help...

Comment: @beck You can use ConnectionRequest's kill() method to cancel download. Suggestion below.
Which means this downloadUrlToAdapt method above won't be returning just the responseCode. It has to return an array or a hashmap containing the responseCode status and the ConnectionRequest object itself so that the kill() method can act on it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The way the browser downloads a file locally is a special case for browsers and unrelated to apps. You can just invoke `Display.execute` with a file and the browser will download it that way although I'm guessing its not what you want since it will not be accessible to you after the fact.

You can show progress using `NetworkManager`'s progress listener. Showing the progress in the notification area is an Android specific behavior and uncommon on iOS. But you might be able to use some of the local notification features https://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

I used it the same way as Sadart Abukari.

Only thing I changed is I used the `ToastBar.Status` instead to display the progress

```
[...]
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addProgressListener((evt) -> {
        if (evt instanceof NetworkEvent) {
            NetworkEvent e = (NetworkEvent) evt;
            if (e.getProgressPercentage() >= 0) {
                status.setProgress(e.getProgressPercentage());
            }
        }
    });

    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
    //Clear the ToastBar
    status.clear();
    return cr.getResponseCode() == 200;
}
```